# Insert traffic lights in MS word

Tags: 2013, document-library, word

Document library has couple of columns that are connected via quick parts with word document that is set as template for that doc. library.
I want to make traffic lights option in word document based on values in one column. Example

> ```
> 1 = red
> 2 = orange
> 3 = green
> ```

Practically I need traffic lights with conditional formatting from Excel in Word but based on library column.

*I tried to copy/paste whole excel table with conditional formatting and it works in word.. But, it cannot be connected or at least I have no knowledge of how to connect that table with library column as I cannot insert quick part in it.*

Bellow is an image of how I see excel table in word with no option to insert quick parts.
[image]

Comment: There's a guide for how to make traffic lights on a list with a small JS + HTML additions, it might also work for libraries. Have a look: http://eimagine.com/creating-a-stoplight-color-coded-status-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list/

Comment: This does not help in any way because calculated columns cannot be put as quick parts in word document. I really appreciate your effort.